# Cookies alert in flutter web

Tags: firebase, flutter, cookies, flutter-web

I am building a web application with flutter and I am using firebase's Authentication ,Firestore, and Storage.

my question is, do I have to show the "accept cookies" alert to my users?

Answer (score 2):

That's an interesting question. I am also building a flutter web app with Firebase as the backend. What I know is that, when your application targets EU you need to provide a privacy policy and a cookie consent manager if you use firebase.
The interesting thing is that Firebase stores the cookies in a indexed Database so when you use a cookie scanner there are no cookies found (at least in my application). But as Firebase stores data in theses indexed Databases locally in the browser you need to inform the user about this otherwise it is not compliant with the GDPR.
There is also a problem that Firebase Auth only uses servers in the US, you need to inform the user about this because they have other privacy standards then the EU.

What I also recommend is that you anonymize all the data collected via Google Analytics in the Firebase console because of the GDPR.

If I was you I would make a banner that says "We just use necessary cookies bla bla" and an accept button next to it.
And link your cookie policy.

But I need to say I am not a lawyer so this couldn't be enough. If you have other information about this please inform me.

Comment: Note that you can also set the location of the firebase server(eg Frankfurt, Germany)

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on you, whether you want to show it or not.And once it is enabled it will be for all the apps.